Find the Expected value of the discrete random variable $Z=X+Y$
Let  $X,Y$ be discrete random variables such that for $k\in \mathbb{R}$
we have
$\mathbb{P}(X = k) = \begin{cases} \frac{5}{6^k} & k \ge 1 \\ 0 & k \le 0, \end{cases} $
and
$\mathbb{P}(Y = k) = \begin{cases} \frac{6}{\pi^2k^2} & k \ge 1 \\ 0 & k \le 0, \end{cases} $
Consider the discrete random variable $Z=X+Y$, the probability that  $Z=n$
is given by $\displaystyle r_{\small n }= \mathbb{P}(Z = n) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \mathbb{P}(X=k) \mathbb{P}(Y = n-k) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \mathbb{P}(X=n-k) \mathbb{P}(Y = k). \qquad \qquad$
I am very confused on how to find the  Expected Value of $Y$, as when you multiply k and $P(Y=k)$, it seems to me that the sum is diverging to infinity.
and
How to Calculate the Probability of   $\mathbb{P}(Z \ge 2)$?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hint:  Use the formula you were told that you can use.

What exactly do you need? The expected value of $Z$ or $Y$? Because as you noticed, $E[Y] = +\infty.$

Hi, i need the expected value of Z

HINT: Note that
$$P(Z = n) = \sum_{k = 1}^n P(X = n - k)P(Y = k) = \frac{30}{\pi 6^n}\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{6^k}{k^2} $$
as for $k < 1$ and $k > n$ the sum above vanishes. Now if you set
$$S(x) = \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{x^k}{k^2},$$
you get
$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(x\frac{d}{dx}S(x)\right) = \sum_{k = 1}^n x^{k-1} = \frac{1 - x^{n+1}}{1 - x}.$$
